# Как скачать файл с переменным значением в url?

Tags: curl, загрузка

Есть файл с URL вида:

```
http://domain.ru/qqq/index.php?q=123456789012345678901234567890123
```

в котором цифровой код после "=" меняется при каждом обновлении страницы.

Нужно реализовать автоматическое скачивание из скрипта с помощью `wget`, `curl` или чего-то подобного, для последующего использования в `cron`.

Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
curl -s https://revisium.com/ai/index.php | \
iconv -f cp1251 | \
sed -rn 's,.*(//revisium\.com/ai/index\.php\?q=[0-9]+)".*,"https:\1",p' | \
head -n 1 | \
xargs curl -s > /tmp/ai-bolit.zip
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score 1):

вероятно, этот *url* надо не угадывать, а извлекать из результатов какого-то другого запроса.

если «цифровой код» состоит только из арабских цифр, то, например, так (используется реализация *sed* для операционной системы *gnu*):

```
$ curl какой-то.другой.url | \
 sed -rn 's,.*(http://domain\.ru/qqq/index\.php\?q=[0-9]+)[^0-9]*,\1,p' | \
 head -n 1 | xargs curl > /путь/к/файлу/куда/сохраняем/результат
```

---

если же «цифровой код» может содержать и, например, шестнадцатиричные цифры `abcdef`, то кусочек:

```
q=[0-9]+
```

можно заменить на:

```
q=[0-9a-f]+
```

а если шестнадцатиричные цифры могут быть и в верхнем и в нижнем регистре, то можно заменить на:

```
q=[0-9a-fA-F]+
```

**дополнение**

на основании приведённой в комментариях информации и просмотра «исходной» страницы, предлагаю следующую корректировку в конвейер и в регулярное выражение для `sed`-а (это вместо первой и второй строки из примера):

```
$ curl какой-то.другой.url | iconv -f cp1251 | \
sed -rn 's,.*(//revisium\.com/ai/index\.php\?q=[0-9]+)".*,"http:\1",p' | \
```

Comment: Не получилось. Файл на выходе нулевой длины. Вот ссылка, откуда нужно скачивать http://revisium.com/ai/index.php

Comment: естественно, потому что у меня лишь пример, основанный на вашей информации. адаптируйте регулярное выражение. во-первых, загляните в выдаваемый код и убедитесь, что `http:` перед искомой вами ссылкой — нет. во-вторых, страница отдаётся в кодировке *cp1251*, и чтобы `sed` корректно ей обрабатывал, надо предварительно конвертировать получаемый *html* в кодировку, используемую в вашей системе (с огромной вероятностью, это совсем не *cp1251*).

Comment: @Magi, я дополнил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо! Все получилось!

Answer (score 0):

Узнать каким образом генерируется цифровой код и использовать полученные знания в запросе `curl`